# bge - EditObjectActuator.time changed at will?

Tags: game-engine

with a script, can we change at will the EditObjectActuator.time ? in my case, I want to  add time of life to an object, while the game is running with a property or a message from another object ... 
I 'm a newbie in scripting with Python, I used to code with logic bricks but I do not know how to do ...

JL[image: The head of my snake]

I've tried many methods uncessfully. So I simplified the code to show what I want to do.
[This is the head of the snake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aImQ.png)

[image: the inactive layer with the tail I want to increase gradually]

[image: Here is the result with a time life of 64]
The problem is "How to increase the timelife at will ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, not only you can change the `actuator.time` attribute in realtime, but you can add an object without an actuator.

## Change the time based on a property

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

act = cont.actuators["AddObjectActuator"]

act.time = own["MyProperty"]
cont.activate(act)
```

## Adding object through script

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
scene = own.scene

# Both objects can be from scene.objects instead of names
scene.addObject("ObjectNameToAdd", "ObjectWhereToAdd", time=own["MyProperty"])
```

More info about this method [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_Scene.html#bge.types.KX_Scene.addObject).

Comment: something is wrong with your api link, says 404 error